# Signs in relations of Brundan--Kleshchev versus Khovanov--Lauda

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, klr-algebras

The following relations in the definition of the quiver Hecke algebra in Brundan--Kleshchev's paper are
$$
  y_r \psi_r e(\underline{i})  =(\psi_r y_{r+1} - \delta_{i_r,i_{r+1}})e(\underline{i});\\
$$
$$
y_{r+1} \psi_r e(\underline{i})  =(\psi_r y_r + \delta_{i_r,i_{r+1}})e(\underline{i});\\
$$
However in Khovanov--Lauda's paper these are given as 
$$
  y_r \psi_r e(\underline{i})  =(\psi_r y_{r+1} + \delta_{i_r,i_{r+1}})e(\underline{i});\\
$$
$$
y_{r+1} \psi_r e(\underline{i})  =(\psi_r y_r - \delta_{i_r,i_{r+1}})e(\underline{i});\\
$$
Does anyone know how to resolve these different definitions?  I would like to do this without changing any of the other relations.  Also, if they are isomorphic why did everyone `change their mind' as to what sign should be used in the first place?

In particular, I would like to use the following as my definition of the KLR algebra (which is just obtained from Brundan-Kleshchev by changing the two relations mentioned above).  Is this okay?

Fix $e\in \{2,3,\ldots\} \cup\{\infty\}$ and let $R$ denote an arbitrary ring. 
The quiver Hecke algebra, $H_n(\kappa)$,   is defined to be the unital, associative $R$-algebra with generators
\begin{align}\label{gnrs}\tag{$\dagger$}
\{e(\underline{i}) \ | \ \underline{i}=(i_1,\dots,i_n)\in (\mathbb{Z}/e\mathbb{Z})^n\}\cup\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}\cup\{\psi_1,\dots,\psi_{n-1}\},
\end{align}
subject to the    relations 
$$e(\underline{i})e(\underline{j}) =\delta_{\underline{i},\underline{j}} e(\underline{i});
$$
$$\sum_{\underline{i} \in   (\mathbb{Z}/e\mathbb{Z})^n } e(\underline{i}) =1; 
y_r  e(\underline{i}) =e(\underline{i})y_r;
$$
$$
\psi_r e(\underline{i})  = e(s_r\underline{i}) \psi_r;
$$ 
$$
y_ry_s =y_sy_r$$
$$\psi_ry _s = {y_s\psi_r}   \;\;   \text{if }\;\; s\neq r,r+1$$
$$
\psi_r\psi_s = \psi_s\psi_r   \;\; \text{if }\;\; |r-s|>1;
$$
$$ \color{red}{ y_r \psi_r e(\underline{i})  =(\psi_r y_{r+1} + \delta_{i_r,i_{r+1}})e(\underline{i})}$$
$$\color{red}{y_{r+1} \psi_r e(\underline{i})  =(\psi_r y_r - \delta_{i_r,i_{r+1}})e(\underline{i})};$$
$$\psi_r^2 e(\underline{i}) =\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }i_r=i_{r+1},\\
e(\underline{i}) & \text{if }i_{r+1}\neq i_r, i_r\pm1,\\
(y_{r+1} - y_r) e(\underline{i}) & \text{if }i_{r+1}=i_r-1 \ \& \ e\neq2,\\
(y_r - y_{r+1}) e(\underline{i}) & \text{if }i_{r+1}=i_r+1 \ \& \ e\neq2,\\
(y_{r+1} - y_r)(y_r - y_{r+1}) e(\underline{i}) & \text{if } i_{r+1}\neq i_r \ \& \ e=2;
\end{cases}$$
$$\psi_r \psi_{r+1} \psi_r  =\begin{cases}
(\psi_{r+1}\psi_r\psi_{r+1} + 1)e(\underline{i})& \text{if }i_r=i_{r+2}=i_{r+1}+1 \ \& \ e\neq2,\\
(\psi_{r+1}\psi_r\psi_{r+1} - 1)e(\underline{i})& \text{if }i_r=i_{r+2}=i_{r+1}-1 \ \& \ e\neq2,\\
(\psi_{r+1}\psi_r\psi_{r+1}+y_r-2y_{r+1}+y_{r+2})e(\underline{i})& \text{if }i_r=i_{r+2}\neq i_{r+1} \ \& \ e=2,\\
(\psi_{r+1}\psi_r\psi_{r+1})e(\underline{i})& \text{otherwise;}
\end{cases} $$
for all admissible $r,s,i,j$.

Comment: I can't solve your sign question, but just a minor correction: should $\kappa$ be playing a role in the definition, in particular controlling the indexing set for the $\underline i$?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it should! Thanks Matt.  Liron Speyer has answered my question for me: the isomorphism between the above definition and Brundan and Kleshchev's is given by sending $\psi_r \to -\psi_r$ and `reversing the orientation on the quiver' i.e. swapping the signs $i_{r+1}\pm1$ to become $i_{r+1}\mp1$.

Comment: Rouquier has shown that, up to some mild assumptions, these algebras are independent of the choice of signs/orientation on the quiver. See Proposition 3.12 of [2-Kac-Moody algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.5023).